# MLM Database Query

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query

I have a question if you know a good way to do this in a mysql query.

The table is like this:

```
-----------------------------------------------
CUSTOMER_ID    | REF_CUSTOMER_ID | NAME       
-----------------------------------------------
1              | NULL            | MARIUS
2              | 1               | PERNILLE
3              | 2               | OLIVIA
4              | 2               | WILLIAM
-----------------------------------------------
```

As you see, this is a customers table. And if the customer is refered by another customer, their id is stored in REF_CUSTOMER_ID.

Do any of you know a good way to count all customers that is refered trough a customer and all customers that is refered trough them again?

EX. Customer 1 has refered 1 customer and that customer has refered two.
That means that in customer 1's count/downline it should be counted to 3.

Comment: Infinitely recursive, or just the two levels?

Comment: So, which one is it, MySQL or tsql?

Comment: Sorry, updated now. It is MySQL

Comment: I think infinite recursive is not possible mysql, you may achieve this by using functions, but I'm not sure

Comment: Is it maby possible to use some kind of mysql loop for this?

Comment: Is it you are looking to count the number of customers referred by 1 customer and position of the particular customer as well